# RESTful API with ESP8266 and arduino mega

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266

Anybody had worked with ESP8266 to post data to RESTful web service? I was trying but it's not posting anything. Tried with a test server:

http://www.posttestserver.com/

```cpp
Serial.println("\nSetting AT+CIPSTART");
String client_conn = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
client_conn += SERVER;
client_conn += "\",";
client_conn += PORT;
Serial.println(client_conn);
Serial2.println(client_conn);
delay(3000);
while (Serial2.available() > 0) {
    c = Serial2.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    if(c=='\n\r' || c == '\r\n')
    Serial.println('\n\r'); 
}
```

It showed me that it got connected 
Now I created POST string

```cpp
String data = "{JSONBODY}";
String post = "POST /post.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
post += "Host: posttestserver.com\r\n";
post += "Content-Length: ";
post += data.length();
post += "\r\n";
post += data;
```

Transmitting data

```cpp
Serial2.print("AT+CIPSEND=");
Serial2.println(post.length());
delay(1000);
if(Serial2.find(">")) {
    Serial2.println(post);
    while (Serial2.available() > 0) {
        c = Serial2.read();
        Serial.print(c);
        if(c=='\n\r' || c == '\r\n')
            Serial.println('\n\r'); 
    }
    delay(5000);
    Serial2.flush();
    delay(5000);
}
```

Returned nothing
Closing connection

```cpp
delay(1000);
Serial2.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
while (Serial2.available() > 0) {
    c = Serial2.read();
    Serial.print(c);
    if(c=='\n\r' || c == '\r\n')
        Serial.println('\n\r'); 
}
delay(5000);
Serial2.flush();
```

Connection closed

But It returned nothing. posttestserver returns data path where it stored.

Comment: 1) There must be **two** CRLFs between the headers and the data, thus replace `post += "\r\n";` by `post += "\r\n\r\n";`. 2) `c == '\r\n'` does not make sense, as \r and \n are _two_ different characters.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try it and let you know @EdgarBonet :)

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks man. Another thing I had to do is, I had to add a 1000uF capacitor across VCC and GND as due to data transmission it fall short of power.